# How to Get Applied Middleware Name of Route into AppServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I am facing a problem, where some API is consuming Server Consumption a lot in AWS. so minimize this I have decided to divide my API into two-part that is (Read and Write) API. now the problem arises in **Laravel 5.7**.I am not getting how to identify which API is being used for reading and writing? I can do this just call a new method that overwrites my hostname from a Controller. but it is lazy task where i have 241 method in my project.  for this, i have created separated **Middleware**.

Suppose i am calling `Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->middleware('ReadAPISourse');`

Anyone has its better solution please tell.

Answer (score 0):

right now i am calling middleware that name is **ReadAPISourse** in all get route. after that, i have fixed my problem.

Its answer was simple. just make a middleware and used that with a route.

`Route::post('login', 'Api\AuthController@login')->middleware('ReadAPISourse');`
but its after i am looking its better solution.

here the problem is the first system is booting with a DB connection then after it is being overwritten by **ReadAPISourse**.